Пишет SDL2.dll отсутствует но при этом он есть VC++
Итак, когда я компилирую проект в Visual Studio 2022 он выдает ошибку мол отсутствует SDL2.dll хоть он и есть.

но при том вроде бы все указано правильно






Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Настройки сборки не влияют на поиск данамических библиотек при запуске исполняемого файла. Dynamic-link library search order Копируйте .dll в папку к исполняемому файлу.

@user7860670 в папку где main.cpp или корневую папку проекта?

В папку к исплняемому файлу, т.е. чтоб они вместе с .exe были
